# Navbar basic css html layout

Tags: html, css

Another basic CSS / HTML question, how this navbar is made (at beginning it is transparent, but after scrolling down, it changes to white and gets smaller) which CSS code is used for this? Thanks!

http://vossendesign.com/purefive/home-concepts.html

Comment: I guess you're new to St.Ov. Please, this website is not meant for you send people to external websites and crawl for your errors/issues. Use the Code tool, show a minimal code that represents your issue **right within your clarified question**. Read [help].

Comment: You should use Chrome Developer Tools in such cases. That will give the understanding how the HTML, CSS and (sometimes) JS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is achieved by adding a CSS class to the navbar with Jquery.
The new class has the new background and size information.
Then a simple "transition: all 0.4s", pure CSS, does the nice transition.